# How to implement multiple local notifications on specific day of weeks at different times in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to implement two local notifications on different days of week (1: on Wednesday 6pm, 2: on Sunday 10am) I applied many things but I am not getting any proper solution. If anyone give solution that will be very helpful, here is my last code which i applied

```
import UserNotifications

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound, .badge], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        let localNotification1 = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification1.alertBody = "Stay up-to-date"
        localNotification1.alertTitle = "New content is now available. Watch now!"
        localNotification1.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
        localNotification1.fireDate = self.getSunday() as Date?
//        localNotification1.soundName =
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification1)

        let localNotification2 = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification2.alertBody = "New videos Uploaded"
        localNotification2.alertTitle = "Dear Doctor, Stay up-to-date. Watch now!"
        localNotification2.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
        localNotification2.fireDate = self.getWednesday() as Date?
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification2)

        return true
}

func getSunday() -> NSDate? {
        let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
        let now: NSDate! = NSDate()

        let date10h = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 2, second: 0, of: now as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options.matchFirst)!

        return date10h as NSDate
    }

    func getWednesday() -> NSDate? {
        let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
        let now: NSDate! = NSDate()

        let date19h = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 3, second: 0, of: now as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options.matchFirst)!
        return date19h as NSDate
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILocalNotification` is deprecated in iOS 10. Use `UNNotificationRequest` instead,

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //requesting for authorization
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in
                if error == nil {
                    self.addMultipleLocalNotification()
            }
        })
    }

    func addMultipleLocalNotification(){
        //creating the notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        //adding title, subtitle, body and badge
        content.title = "Notification title "
        content.subtitle = "Notification sub-title "
        content.body = "We are learning about iOS Local Notification"
        content.badge = 1

        var sundayDate = DateComponents()
        sundayDate.weekday = 0 // which is Sunday
        sundayDate.hour = 10
        sundayDate.minute = 00

        var wedDate = DateComponents()
        wedDate.weekday = 3 // which is wednesday
        wedDate.hour = 18
        wedDate.minute = 00

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: sundayDate, repeats: true)
         let trigger1 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: wedDate, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notificationName", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        let request2 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notificationName2", content: content, trigger: trigger1)


        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        //adding the notification to notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request2, withCompletionHandler: nil)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(
        completionHandler: { (notficiations) in
            for localNotification in notficiations {
                print(localNotification)
            }
        })
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        //displaying the ios local notification when app is in foreground
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```

Comment: I have Integrated this but it's not working as well, it's not even fire a single notification

Comment: it's working fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7EcL.jpg( scheduled two notifications at 4:00 pm and 4:01 pm ). Can you check,  if the app is printing the pending notifications in the getPendingNotificationRequests method?

Comment: i have put this code in Appdelegate, can it make Any issue?

Comment: use methods of the app delegate to update the state of the app when it enters the foreground or moves to the background. Please try it in ViewController.

Comment: No. I have not changed anything.

Comment: so maybe i was An os issue because i m using xcode 11 and i have tried All that things but it is still not working

Comment: No, that's not the issue. Check list , 1. are you getting the push notification pop up asking the user permission? 2. Are you getting any logs in the console regarding the pending notifications ? 3. are you getting any other error messages in console?

Comment: 1. yes i m getting push notification popup 2. i m getting below code in my console

Comment: <UNNotificationRequest: 0x6000021c6c10; identifier: notificationName, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x600001a41a40; title: Notification title , subtitle: Notification sub-title , body: We are learning about iOS Local Notification, summaryArgument: , summaryArgumentCount: 0, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
), badge: (null), sound: (null),, trigger: <UNCalendarNotificationTrigger: 0x600002fceae0; dateComponents: <NSDateComponents: 0x6000018423c0>
    Hour: 19
    Minute: 55
    Weekday: 3, repeats: YES>>

Comment: <UNNotificationRequest: 0x6000021c4300; identifier: notificationName2, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x600001a40480; title: Notification title , subtitle: Notification sub-title , body: We are learning about iOS Local Notification, summaryArgument: , summaryArgumentCount: 0, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
), badge: (null), sound: (null),, trigger: <UNCalendarNotificationTrigger: 0x600002fceea0; dateComponents: <NSDateComponents: 0x600001841080>
    Hour: 19
    Minute: 56
    Weekday: 3, repeats: YES>>

Comment: Sunday is 1, wednesday weekday is 4. so correct it. you ll receive notification.Even the badge must return value as 1.

Comment: i have changed it As you say and it's working, Thankyou so much.

Comment: Did the above answer work ? If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.